# How to Get JSON Array Within JSON Object?

Tags: java, android, json

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "Choc Cake",
            "Image": "1.jpg",
            "Category": "Meal",
            "Method": "",
            "Ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "1 Cup Ice"
                },
                {
                    "name": "1 Bag Beans"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "Ice Cake",
            "Image": "dfdsfdsfsdfdfdsf.jpg",
            "Category": "Meal",
            "Method": "",
            "Ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "1 Cup Ice"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is how I am getting the id and name, you can see this part works fine in returning JSON values that are not array values.

```
//getting whole json string
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

//extracting data array from json string
JSONArray ja_data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
int length = jsonObj .length(); 

//loop to get all json objects from data json array
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) 
{
    JSONObject jObj = ja_data.getJSONObject(i);
    Toast.makeText(this, jObj.getString("Name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // getting inner array Ingredients
    JSONArray ja = jObj.getJSONArray("Ingredients");
    int len = ja.length();


}
```

Now i'm trying to get the values from the ingredients array and I am not sure how to get them? This is what I have been trying thus far.

```
//getting whole json string
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

//extracting data array from json string
JSONArray ja_data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
int length = jsonObj .length(); 

//loop to get all json objects from data json array
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) 
{
    JSONObject jObj = ja_data.getJSONObject(i);
    Toast.makeText(this, jObj.getString("Name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // getting inner array Ingredients
    JSONArray ja = jObj.getJSONArray("Ingredients");
    int len = ja.length();

    // getting json objects from Ingredients json array
    for(int j=0; j<len; j++)
    {
        JSONObject json = ja.getJSONObject(j);
        Toast.makeText(this, json.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

But doing it this way is not working, how can I get it to work?

Comment: Please explain _"does not work"_.

Answer (score 11):

Solved, use array list of string to get name from Ingredients. Use below code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

//extracting data array from json string
JSONArray ja_data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
int length = ja_data.length();

//loop to get all json objects from data json array
for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
    JSONObject jObj = ja_data.getJSONObject(i);
    Toast.makeText(this, jObj.getString("Name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // getting inner array Ingredients
    JSONArray ja = jObj.getJSONArray("Ingredients");
    int len = ja.length();
    ArrayList<String> Ingredients_names = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=0; j<len; j++){
        JSONObject json = ja.getJSONObject(j);
        Ingredients_names.add(json.getString("name"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++){
    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = json.getString("id");
    String name=json.getString("name");
    JSONArray ingArray = json.getJSONArray("Ingredients") // here you are going   to get ingredients
    for(int j=0;j<ingArray.length;j++){
        JSONObject ingredObject= ingArray.getJSONObject(j);
        String ingName = ingredObject.getString("name");//so you are going to get   ingredient name
        Log.e("name",ingName); // you will get 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
int length = jArray.length();

   for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
      {
        JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = jObj.optString("id");
        String name=jObj.optString("name");

        JSONArray ingredientArray = jObj.getJSONArray("Ingredients");
        int size = ingredientArray.length();
        ArrayList<String> Ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
               {
                    JSONObject json = ja.getJSONObject(j);
                    Ingredients.add(json.optString("name"));
                }


       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `int length = jsonObj.length();` should be `int length = ja_data.length();`

Comment: this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {}.getType();
                List<Data>     cartProductList = gson.fromJson(response.body().get("data"), listType);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+cartProductList.get(0).getCity(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and explain what you are doing, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for more guidance.