# Convert JsonArray to JsonObject

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I have this JSON array:

```
[{
   "MOTIVO": "ok",
   "ESTATUS": "10",
   "TIPO": "1",
   "ACCMOTIDN": "2",
   "AVMVOR1IDN": "31089",
   "AVMVORIDN": "23163",
   "SPCHRZIDN": "75"
}, {
     "MOTIVO": "ok",
     "ESTATUS": "10",
     "TIPO": "1",
     "ACCMOTIDN": "2",
     "AVMVOR1IDN": "31090",
     "AVMVORIDN": "23163",
     "SPCHRZIDN": "75"
}]
```

I validate with JSONLint and it is a valid JSON. How can I convert into a `jsonObjects`? This is what I have at this moment:

```
public ArrayList<Object[]>Auth_Rej_Order(String obj_auth,mPedidoDet 
mpedidodet)
 {
     try
     {
         res_array=new ArrayList();
         obj_auth_json=new JSONArray(obj_auth);
         obj_auth_list=new ArrayList<>();
         obj_auth_list_map=new HashMap<>();
         JSONObject obj_json;
         for(int i= obj_auth_json.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
         {
             obj_json=new JSONObject(obj_auth_json);
             Iterator<?> keys = obj_json.keys();
             while( keys.hasNext() ) 
             {
                String key = keys.next().toString();
                obj_auth_list_map.put(key,obj_json.get(key));
             }
             obj_auth_list.add(obj_auth_list_map);
         }

     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         //Error inesperado.
        res_array.clear();
        res_obj_array=new Object[1];
        res_obj_array[0]="001";
        res_array.add(res_obj_array);
     }

     return res_array;
 }
```

I'm trying with:

```
obj_json=new JSONObject(obj_auth_json)
obj_json=new JSONObject(obj_auth_json.get(position))
obj_json=new JSONObject(obj_auth_json.getJSONObject(position))
obj_json=new JSONObject(obj_auth_json.getJSONArray(position));
```

and any of them worked.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Have a look at [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get JSON Array Within JSON Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624166/how-to-get-json-array-within-json-object)