# JSON index out of range

Tags: java, android, json

I'm currently trying to process some JSON but it's given me an error saying that "Index 0 out of range [0..0)" the affected line is the one that is commented out.

```
JSONObject parentObject3 = new JSONObject(finalJSON3);
JSONArray parentArray3 = parentObject3.getJSONArray("players");
//JSONObject finalObject3 = parentArray3.getJSONObject(0);

tempGameBans = finalObject3.getInt("NumberOfBans");
tempVacBans = finalObject3.getInt("NumberOfMutes");;
```

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "userID": "5648131",
            "NumberOfBans": 0,
            "NumberOfMutes": 1,
        }
    ]

}
```

Edit: Currently I am only looking for 1 object per JSON URL so the Index should always be 0, unlike the possible duplicate which seems to be looking for multiple objects.

Edit 2: I found out what the issue is and it's due to the JSON not being correctly sent from my server. Thanks for the help anyway guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get JSON Array Within JSON Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624166/how-to-get-json-array-within-json-object)

Comment: for the future: try validate your json on jsonlint.com ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling some attribute either not in the `JsonObject` or the attribute value at that specified index doesn't exist.

Comment: Every value I am calling is in the JSON Object, so I'm not sure why it's giving me an error.

Comment: `JSONObject object = new JSONObject();` `object.get(1)` instead of getInt(); Please try this.I also some times get this error.It may be reason of value not being assigned!Please post your final JSON

Answer (score 2):

```
    String jsonString = new String("{\"players\": [{\"userID\": \"5648131\",\"NumberOfBans\": 0,\"NumberOfMutes\": 1}]}");
    JSONObject parentObject3 = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray parentArray3 = parentObject3.getJSONArray("players");
    JSONObject finalObject3 = parentArray3.getJSONObject(0);

    System.out.println(finalObject3.getInt("userID"));
    System.out.println(finalObject3.getInt("NumberOfBans"));
    System.out.println(finalObject3.getInt("NumberOfMutes"));
```

This is working fine, so there has to be some another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove the **","** at the end of **"NumberOfMutes": 1,**.

Comment: I think that was me who put that in when I was typing the question as it's not in the final JSON

Comment: I guess this has something to do with your actual JSON. So please provide the final JSON of your problem.