# How to extract JSONArray and JSONObject from a JSON in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

How can I extract JSON Array and JSON Object from JSON.

Below is the input:

```
{
    "messageName": "ReportCard",
    "orgId": "Org1",
    "comment": true,
    "Fields": [{
       "objectId": "1234-56789-asdv",
       "fieldId": "1245-7852-dhjd"
    },
    {
       "objectId": "1234-56hgjgh789-hjjhj",
       "fieldId": "12sdf45-78sfg52-dfjhjd"
    }]
}
```

I want JSON Array and JSON Object separately and output should be like:

JSONArray

```
"Fields":[{ "objectId": "1234-56789-asdv",
           "fieldId": "1245-7852-dhjd"},{
           "objectId": "1234-56hgjgh789-hjjhj",
           "fieldId": "12sdf45-78sfg52-dfjhjd"}]
```

and JSON Object should be like:

```
{
  "messageName": "ReportCard",
        "orgId": "Org1",
        "comment": true
}
```

Comment: You should share code you tried to apply against given problem. Can you also put more details about what kind of json library you use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get JSON Array Within JSON Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624166/how-to-get-json-array-within-json-object)

Comment: i'm using "json-simple" Library. and input is a @requestParam parameter of post api of Springboot project ,i want to save jsonObject in a different Collection and JsonArray in different Collection of mongodb. JSONObject is data member of a model class and JSON Array is a Diffrent model class in the Project

Comment: @Thekamble can you suggest what should be right format of it?? Thanks

Comment: @Abhinav I think that person wants to combine it and i want to split it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its pretty simple if you know java JSON API

```
String jsonString="{
    "messageName": "ReportCard",
    "orgId": "Org1",
    "comment": true,
    "Fields": [{
       "objectId": "1234-56789-asdv",
       "fieldId": "1245-7852-dhjd"
    },
    {
       "objectId": "1234-56hgjgh789-hjjhj",
       "fieldId": "12sdf45-78sfg52-dfjhjd"
    }]
}"
JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(); //creating new Jobject
// putting data to JSONObject 
jo.put("messageName", jObject.getString("messageName").toString()); 
jo.put("orgId", jObject.getString("orgId").toString()); 
jo.put("comment", jObject.getString("comment").toString()); 

JSONArray Fields= jObject.getJSONArray("Fields");//extract field array
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(); //creating new json array.
int Arraylength = Fields.length();
for(int i=0;i<Arraylength;i++)
{
    Map m = new LinkedHashMap(2); 
    JSONObject ArrayjObj = Fields.getJSONObject(i);
    m.put("objectId", ArrayjObj.getString("objectId").toString()); 
    m.put("fieldId", ArrayjObj.getString("fieldId").toString()); 
    // adding map to list 
    ja.add(m); 
 }
JSONObject fieldsObj = new JSONObject(); 
fieldsObj.put("Fields", ja); // Fields Array Created
```

for JSON api refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject)

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch particular values as per keys into a json object and rest into a separate  json array

```
String strJSON =" {\"id\":\"12\",\"messageName\":\"ReportCard\" , \"Fields\":[{\"objectId\": \"1234-56789-asdv\", \"fieldId\": \"1245-7852-dhjd\"},{\"objectId\": \"1234-56hgjgh789-hjjhj\", \"fieldId\": \"12sdf45-78sfg52-dfjhjd\"}]   }";

 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jo1= new JSONObject();
JSONObject jo= new JSONObject(strJSON);
  ja=  jo.getJSONArray( "Fields");
jo1.put("messageName",jo.get(messageName));
jo1.put("orgId",jo.get(orgId));
```