# How to convert a json String to json array using java and Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json String and there is an array inside it I wan to fetch only array part.

JSON String:

```
{
    "jsonKeywords": [
        {
            "xmlNodeKWId": 0,
            "xmlNodeId": 35,
            "nodeKeyword": "dfdfdf",
            "keywordPosition": "Top",
            "keywordPrefix": "",
            "keywordSuffix": "abcd",
            "valueInLine": 0,
            "keywordMatchPattern": "",
            "templateId": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert it into only:

```
[
        {
            "xmlNodeKWId": 0,
            "xmlNodeId": 35,
            "nodeKeyword": "dfdfdf",
            "keywordPosition": "Top",
            "keywordPrefix": "",
            "keywordSuffix": "abcd",
            "valueInLine": 0,
            "keywordMatchPattern": "",
            "templateId": 3
        }
]
```

I am using Gson library to handel JSON.
Is it possible to do that.

Comment: @B001ᛦ comments like this are neither friendly nor helpful. A single link to a similar issue would be much appreciated...

Comment: Can anyone give me a link? where i can find this or comment what to write in google o search that.

Comment: Have a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490789/json-parsing-using-gson-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

Response class:

```
 public class Response{

    @SerializedName("jsonKeywords")
    private List<JsonKeywordsItem> jsonKeywords;

    public void setJsonKeywords(List<JsonKeywordsItem> jsonKeywords){
        this.jsonKeywords = jsonKeywords;
    }

    public List<JsonKeywordsItem> getJsonKeywords(){
        return jsonKeywords;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "Response{" + 
            "jsonKeywords = '" + jsonKeywords + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

JsonKeywordsItem  class:

```
public class JsonKeywordsItem {

@SerializedName("keywordSuffix")
private String keywordSuffix;

@SerializedName("valueInLine")
private int valueInLine;

@SerializedName("keywordMatchPattern")
private String keywordMatchPattern;

@SerializedName("nodeKeyword")
private String nodeKeyword;

@SerializedName("keywordPrefix")
private String keywordPrefix;

@SerializedName("keywordPosition")
private String keywordPosition;

@SerializedName("templateId")
private int templateId;

@SerializedName("xmlNodeKWId")
private int xmlNodeKWId;

@SerializedName("xmlNodeId")
private int xmlNodeId;

public void setKeywordSuffix(String keywordSuffix) {
    this.keywordSuffix = keywordSuffix;
}

public String getKeywordSuffix() {
    return keywordSuffix;
}

public void setValueInLine(int valueInLine) {
    this.valueInLine = valueInLine;
}

public int getValueInLine() {
    return valueInLine;
}

public void setKeywordMatchPattern(String keywordMatchPattern) {
    this.keywordMatchPattern = keywordMatchPattern;
}

public String getKeywordMatchPattern() {
    return keywordMatchPattern;
}

public void setNodeKeyword(String nodeKeyword) {
    this.nodeKeyword = nodeKeyword;
}

public String getNodeKeyword() {
    return nodeKeyword;
}

public void setKeywordPrefix(String keywordPrefix) {
    this.keywordPrefix = keywordPrefix;
}

public String getKeywordPrefix() {
    return keywordPrefix;
}

public void setKeywordPosition(String keywordPosition) {
    this.keywordPosition = keywordPosition;
}

public String getKeywordPosition() {
    return keywordPosition;
}

public void setTemplateId(int templateId) {
    this.templateId = templateId;
}

public int getTemplateId() {
    return templateId;
}

public void setXmlNodeKWId(int xmlNodeKWId) {
    this.xmlNodeKWId = xmlNodeKWId;
}

public int getXmlNodeKWId() {
    return xmlNodeKWId;
}

public void setXmlNodeId(int xmlNodeId) {
    this.xmlNodeId = xmlNodeId;
}

public int getXmlNodeId() {
    return xmlNodeId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return
            "JsonKeywordsItem{" +
                    "keywordSuffix = '" + keywordSuffix + '\'' +
                    ",valueInLine = '" + valueInLine + '\'' +
                    ",keywordMatchPattern = '" + keywordMatchPattern + '\'' +
                    ",nodeKeyword = '" + nodeKeyword + '\'' +
                    ",keywordPrefix = '" + keywordPrefix + '\'' +
                    ",keywordPosition = '" + keywordPosition + '\'' +
                    ",templateId = '" + templateId + '\'' +
                    ",xmlNodeKWId = '" + xmlNodeKWId + '\'' +
                    ",xmlNodeId = '" + xmlNodeId + '\'' +
                    "}";
}
}




Gson gson = new Gson();
      Response response = gson.fromJson("Your response string", Response.class);
            List<JsonKeywordsItem> mList = response.getJsonKeywords();
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick way would be to use `Map` and unchecked casts to extract the `jsonKeywords` element. Assuming you read the JSON into `inputJson` variable:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, ?> map = gson.fromJson(inputJson, Map.class);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(map.get("jsonKeywords")));
```

will output:

```
[{"xmlNodeKWId":0.0,"xmlNodeId":35.0,"nodeKeyword":"dfdfdf","keywordPosition":"Top","keywordPrefix":"","keywordSuffix":"abcd","valueInLine":0.0,"keywordMatchPattern":"","templateId":3.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use JSONARRAY to get data array from JSON:**

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("jsonKeywords");
```

**Also, [Refer This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624166/how-to-get-json-array-within-json-object)**